# For spectral clustering,

Tags: spectral-analysis

My professor is teaching us spectral clustering but unfortunately he gave a hand-wavy introduction and left most of the details out, so I'm trying to fill them in on my own.

He stated, suppose we have a graph $G=(V,E,W)$ where $W$ is the weight matrix and there are $n$ vertices. The degree matrix $D$ is defined as a diagonal matrix with entries $d_{ii} = \sum_{j=1}^{n}w_{ij}$. Then the Laplacian matrix is defined as $L=D-W$. He said define

$$\tilde{W} = D^{-1/2} W D^{-1/2}$$

Then the symmetric normalized Laplacian is defined as 
$$\tilde{L}=D^{1/2}(I-\tilde{W})D^{1/2}$$

He said, let $\lambda_1 < \cdots < \lambda_R$ be the largest eigenvalues of $\tilde{W}$. Let $v_1,...,v_R$ be the corresponding eigenvectors. He said then

$$\tilde{W}v_k = \lambda_k v_k$$ and the "embedding" of a point $x_i$ in the new space is $$e(x_i)=\lbrace v_{ki}\rbrace_{k=1}^{R}$$

I learned from this famous paper more of the details:

https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~malik/papers/SM-ncut.pdf

In particular, they show that separating points into two clusters $A$ and $B$ can be set up as

$$\underset{y}{\text{argmin}} \frac{y^TLy}{y^TDy}$$ 
subject to $y^TD1 = 0$.

I understand that the eigensystem

$$(D-W)y=\lambda Dy$$

solves this problem and, setting $z= D^{-1/2}y$, we get

$$D^{-1/2} L D^{-1/2} z = \lambda z$$

which is equivalent to

$$\tilde{L}z=\lambda z$$

I don't understand how to get from here to $$\tilde{W}v_k = \lambda_k v_k$$

I tried doing

$$\begin{align*}
\tilde{L}z&=\lambda z\\
(I-\tilde{W}) z&=\lambda z\\
z - \tilde{W}z &= \lambda z\\
\tilde{W}z &= (\lambda + 1)z\\ 
\end{align*} $$

But I'm really unclear if this is sensible. Is this correct? If so, why are the eigenvalues of $\tilde{W}$ simply the eigenvalues of $\tilde{L}$ plus 1?